# Same Mobile app connecting to multiple Ealstic Bean Stalk based on geolocation

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, geolocation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have a android/ios app, which talks to a AWS backend /databased hosted in Mumbai India... We are planning to introduce the app in US , The AWS backend / database for the app will be hosted in US....

We are planning to maintain a single instance of the app and based on geolocation,
connect it to appropriate AWS backend backend . Is there any other easy way to do this

Comment: Can you provide more details about the architecture of your backend on AWS

Comment: Yes... we have a series of ReST API running on EC2 instances. These are exposed via a Load balancer / Elastic bean stak